# MYSQL IF(expr1,expr2,expr3) but I don’t want any expr3 (if expr3 then don’t output anything

Tags: php, mysql

As the title says, I just want an output if the if is matched, if it’s not matched then I don’t want any output.

I currently have this, but it gives an error obviously

```
...rFormat=IF(ISNULL(rFormat), VALUES(rFormat),UNCHANGED)…
```

I looked around http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/control-flow-functions.html but didn’t really find out how to do it.

This question is kinda related to [Only update the MYSQL field if the field contains null or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837912/only-update-the-mysql-field-if-the-field-contains-null-or-0)

This is used in context of: (as seen in the above URL)

```
………
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
rFormat=VALUES(rFormat),
rFiles=IF(ISNULL(rFiles), VALUES(rFiles), VALUES(rSizeMB)),
rText=VALUES(rText);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do

```
IF(ISNULL(rFormat), VALUES(rFormat), rFormat)
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by calling VALUES() at this point, however.

Comment: This is part of a long query as seen in this other question I posted earlier, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837912/only-update-the-mysql-field-if-the-field-contains-null-or-0 I don’t want to output rFormat for expr3 as then it would overwrite what is already in the field which is what I don’t want.

Comment: No problem. Greg's answer is far better than mine!

Comment: Greg’s doesn’t work either, not inside my "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” query :( Thanks for trying though.

Comment: "it would overwrite what is already in the field " - but you'd use the value that is already in the field, so there are no changes.

Comment: Oh you are so right!
I was thinking it was $rFormat.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `WHERE rFormat IS NULL` instead of `IF`.

Comment: This doesn’t work in the query I’m using it in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837912/only-update-the-mysql-field-if-the-field-contains-null-or-0

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Never mind, Tim solved the problem.
Thanks for the help all the same, I may need your solution later on, I keep a log of this all :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

rFiles = COALESCE(existingColumnValue,'$newValue')

COALESCE returns the first non-null value. Note that you will need quotes around the $newValue if it is a string, and don't forget to escape. You won't use the quotes around the column name (existingColumnValue). If you are also looking for rows that have a (INT) 0 as the value as well as NULL, you might want to try this:

rFiles = CASE existingColumnValue 
WHEN NULL THEN '$newValue' 
WHEN 0 THEN '$newValue' 
ELSE existingColumnValue 
END CASE

I had to change your column names so that I could better express the solution. I hope that you still understand. I was assuming that the $newValue is not another column in the database, but a variable being passed from your script.